# How to call a variable in conf file into a python script or file?

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have a variable "app_version" in a file release.conf. Using that value I have to download a file from a url using urllib. My python version is 2.6.6. Below is what I have so far:

import os
import urllib
from urllib import urlretrieve
import tarfile

```
os.chdir('/tmp/')
surl = "http://xxxx.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/xxxx/xxxx/tgz/xxxx.ear/{}/xxxx.ear-{}.tar.gz".format('app_version')
slurl =  "http://xxxx.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/com/xxxx/xxxx/tgz/xxxx.ear/{}/xxxx.ear-{}.tar.gz".format('app_version')
surlobj = urllib.urlretrieve(surl, 'xxxx.ear-{}.tar.gz').format('app_version')
slurlobj = urllib.urlretrieve(slurl, 'xxxx.ear-{}.tar.gz').format('app_version')
sEAR = 'xxxx.ear-{}.tar.gz'.format('app_version')
slEAR = 'xxxx.ear-{}.tar.gz'.format('app_version')
tar = tarfile.open(sEAR)
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
tar1 = tarfile.open(slEAR)
tar1.extractall()
tar1.close()
os.remove(sEAR)
os.remove(slEAR)
```

I am aware that my code is incomplete. Please help me out in adding the missing lines of code.

Comment: _I am aware that my code is complete_ I think you meant "is not complete".

Answer (score 0):

You have to either read the content of the release.conf or eval it, so that the variable app_version has the value for the app_version. So app_version becomes a Python variable. Then, you should change all the formatting function to use app_version variable. For example:

```
 sEAR = 'xxxx.ear-{}.tar.gz'.format(app_version)
```

When app_version is a variable

```
>>> app_version="4.6."
>>> 'xxxx.ear-{}.tar.gz'.format(app_version)
'xxxx.ear-4.6..tar.gz'
```

Whereas if app_version is a string (vs a variable)

```
>>> 'xxxx.ear-{}.tar.gz'.format('app_version')
'xxxx.ear-app_version.tar.gz'
```

Answer (score 0):

If `release.conf` is a standard ConfigParser-type file like this:

```
[section name]
item1=foo
item2=bar

[another section name]
item3=xyz
```

Then you can do this to get the value of any item in the file:

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('release.conf')
app_version = config.get('section', 'item')
```

And then use `app_version` as a regular variable:

```
surl = "http://whatever.com/xxxx.ear{0}.tar.gz".format(app_version)
```